# Rails returning empty assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

From "out of nowhere" (as it seems), all of a sudden my Rails 3.2.21 development environment started returning empty assets after a few successful requests from my browser. The network tab looks like this:

[image]

I'm running this on OS X 10.10.2. The upgrade from 10.10.1 is the most noteworthy thing that has recently happened on this machine. I cannot relate it to new gems either, since it seems to happen with the gemset that still worked fine last week. Also, it happens in all browsers I've tried (Chrome, Safari and Firefox). Clearing browser cache doesn't help. Clearing the asset cache doesn't help (e.g. with `rake assets:clean`). The only thing that helps is killing the rails server and then starting it again. I'm now almost always down to 1 successul request and then it breaks again.

Other details: I'm running ruby 2.0.0p598 via rbenv. The webserver is thin_glazed.

I'm completely stuck... is there anyone who has a clue as to what might be going on? Thanks!